# Adding <td> to one row of table but not all changes row position

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table like this

```
<table>
<tr>example1</tr>
<tr>example2</tr>
<tr>example3</tr>
</table>
```

and it works fine but if I add `<td>` to the first row and not the others it goes straight to the bottom - http://jsfiddle.net/sLd1L92t/1/

```
<table>
<tr><td>example1</td></tr>
<tr>example2</tr>
<tr>example3</tr>
</table>
```

Is there any way I can have the `<td>` in just one row and not have that row repositioned?

Comment: That is just invalid HTML – you _need_ at least one table cell inside a table row.

Comment: Your text is being kicked out of the table since it's semantically incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `<td>` to each row, like so:

```
<div>  
<table border="1">
    <tr><td>example1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>example2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>example3</td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

(I added a `border` to make it clear where the cell boundaries are)

And if you want the second two rows to fill the width of the table, then use colspan which tells the row to span multiple columns:

```
<div>  
<table border="1">
    <tr><td>exampleA</td><td>exampleB</td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2">example2</td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2">example3</td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Adding in the <td> is correct HTML, so I don't believe there is a way to do what you want.

Why are you trying to write the table that way? You can probably make it work using <div> tags instead.